# htaccess redirect all images, css, and javascript, without specifying a subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to figure out how to redirect all css, image, and javascript requests to a new URL, keeping the path structure.

The files are not all in subdirectories (for example, images.mydomain.com), they could be in any folder.

How can I redirect requests for these file types to a new domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `/DocumentRoot/.htaccess` OR `/images/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^cdn\.tivahost\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|css|js)$ http://cdn.tivahost.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302,NC]
```

Comment: Would that also cause the address in the browser to change as well? (The desired result)

Comment: Yes it will change the URL in browser also as this rule is using `R` flag for that.

Comment: Test it out and let me know if there is any problem.

Comment: When I try this and open an image on our server, it still shows the original URL, and doesn't redirect.

Comment: It is set as the first rule, and I don't think there are any other htaccess files above the one I am editing.

Comment: The rules works at the root level, but not in the /images/ folder. There is no htaccess file in the /images/ folder, or any rules that I can see that should affect this. Does your RewriteRule work in folders other than the root folder?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66518/discussion-between-anubhava-and-sherwin-flight).

Comment: Responding to your comment in chat. This rule doesn't check whether a file exists or not and just does a redirect to cdn domain.